# How do i export this Script to csv

Tags: powershell

#I can't figure out where to place the Export-csv ...

It doesn't seem to work when I put it on the end with a pipe

```
foreach($ADMachineInOU in $(Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com" | Select -ExpandProperty Name))
    {
        # Test if machine is online
        if(Test-Connection -ComputerName $ADMachineInOU -Count 1 -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue)
            {
                Write-Host $ADMachineInOU -ForegroundColor Green
                $CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ADMachineInOU
                
                Get-NetAdapter -CimSession $CimSession -Name "Wi-Fi" | select PSComputerName,DriverVersion
                Remove-CimSession -CimSession $CimSession
            }  
        else
            {
                Write-Host $ADMachineInOU -ForegroundColor Gray 
            } 
        Remove-Variable CimSession,ADMachineInOU -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    }
```

Comment: This is very vague, what are you trying to export? The properties returned from `Get-NetAdapter`? If so,  `Get-NetAdapter -CimSession $CimSession -Name "Wi-Fi" | select PSComputerName,DriverVersion | Export-Csv -Path 'C:\my\path.csv' `

Comment: I would like the result of the offline machines and the machines which bring back results i.e.
PSComputerName | DriverVersion

Comment: That only seems to give me the last machine queries in a csv. not the whole list

Comment: Use the `-Append` switch parameter with `Export-Csv`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest something like this:

```
$ADComputers = Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com"

$Report = @()
foreach ($ADComputer in $ADComputers)
{
    $HostName = $ADComputer.name
    
    # Test if machine is online
    $Ping = Test-Connection $HostName -Count -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue

    If ($Ping)
    {
        Write-Host $HostName -ForegroundColor Green
        $CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $HostName
        $Adapter = Get-NetAdapter -CimSession $CimSession -Name "Wi-Fi"
        $Hash = @{
            Hostname = $HostName
            Hardware = "Wi-Fi"
            PSComputerName = $Adapter.PSComputerName
            DriverVersion = $Adapter.DriverVersion
        }
        Remove-CimSession -CimSession $CimSession
        $Report += New-Object psobject -Property $hash

    }  
    else
    {
        Write-Host $ADMachineInOU -ForegroundColor Gray 
    }
} 

$Report | export-csv "c:\Temp\Report.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply capture the results from `Get-NetAdapter` in a variable. Make sure only wanted objects are output in the foreach loop:

```
$searchBase = "OU=Win10Modern,OU=LN,OU=Workstations,DC=cooley,DC=com"
$result = foreach($ADMachineInOU in (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -SearchBase $searchBase).Name) {
    # Test if machine is online
    if (Test-Connection -ComputerName $ADMachineInOU -Count 1 -Quiet -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue) {
        Write-Host $ADMachineInOU -ForegroundColor Green
        $CimSession = New-CimSession -ComputerName $ADMachineInOU
            
        Get-NetAdapter -CimSession $CimSession -Name "Wi-Fi" | select PSComputerName,DriverVersion
        # ignore the output from Remove-CimSession to not pollute the captured results
        $null = Remove-CimSession -CimSession $CimSession
    }  
    else {
        Write-Host "Computer $ADMachineInOU did not respond.." -ForegroundColor Gray 
    } 
} 
# now export to Csv file
$result | Export-Csv -Path 'X:\Path\to\Output.Csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

P.S. I think you want to use `-Name '*Wi-Fi*'` for Get-NetAdapter..